# JSON RPC transfer of ERC20 Tokens with Parity

Tags: parity, json-rpc, erc-20

How can I use Parity with JSON RPC to send and receive ERC20 tokens?

Comment: Did you find this out? Also looking for this

Comment: I ended up using Geth. I could help if you are interested.